# how to fetch data from two tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have to find out the output as class name and number of students in each class? My both tables are-

```
CREATE TABLE student(Fields_ID INT, Name VARCHAR(20));
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(30,'JYOTI');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(31,'KIRTI');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(32,'YOGITA');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(33,'RASHMI');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(34,'NUPUR');
SELECT * FROM student;

CREATE TABLE class(Fields_ID INT, Name VARCHAR(20));
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(30,'FIRST');
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(31,'SECOND');
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(32,'THIRD');
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(33,'FOURTH');
        INSERT INTO class(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(34,'FIFTH');
SELECT * FROM class;
```

I was trying to return the required out from the following code but it does not return same.
Any idea why it is not returning the right values.I am a beginner in MySql so I am unable to find out the problem.

```
SELECT class.Name , COUNT(student.name)
From class INNER JOIN student
    ON class.Fields_ID=student.Fields_ID;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using aggregate functions you should group them like `GROUP BY class.Name` so you will get the count of students in each class,other wise you will get a single row not the results per group i.e students per class

```
SELECT class.Name , COUNT(student.name)
From class INNER JOIN student
    ON class.Fields_ID=student.Fields_ID
GROUP BY class.Name;
```

[GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

[See fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fa35/2)