# How can I fetch data from more than two tables?

Tags: mysql

I have to return the number of students who have scored more than the overall average as output.

Here are my two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE student(Fields_ID INT, Name VARCHAR(20));
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(30,'JYOTI');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(31,'KIRTI');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(32,'YOGITA');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(33,'RASHMI');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(34,'NUPUR');
SELECT * FROM student;

CREATE TABLE Marks(Fields_ID INT, Student_ID INT NOT NULL,marks INT NOT NULL);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (30,40,100);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (31,41,88);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (32,42,72);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (33,43,33);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (34,44,15);
SELECT * FROM Marks;
```

This is the code I tried to return the output I wanted, but I was unable to form the correct syntax.

```
SELECT COUNT(student.name)
From student INNER JOIN Marks
    ON Marks.Fields_ID = student.Fields_ID
HAVING marks>AVG(marks);
```

How should I do it instead?

Comment: I believe for `AVG()` and `COUNT()` you would need to `GROUP`.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967954/how-to-fetch-data-from-three-or-more-tables

Comment: They are different .In this question I have to find out only the number of students who have scored more than the overall average.

Comment: You have four questions besides this one. I strongly belief in `Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime´. What have you learned from your questions so far? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967490/how-to-fetch-data-from-two-tables-in-mysql,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967759/fetching-data-from-two-tables,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967954/how-to-fetch-data-from-three-or-more-tables,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968300/how-to-fetch-data-from-more-than-one-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(student.name)
From student 
INNER JOIN Marks
    ON Marks.Fields_ID = student.Fields_ID
WHERE Marks.marks>( SELECT AVG(marks)
                    FROM marks );
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0dd8ad/3